# Swapping two columns in h:dataTable based on condition

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I would like to swap two columns in JSF `h:dataTable` based on a condition. For instance if a user chooses red, then the column with red values comes first. If he chooses the other color say blue then the column with blue values comes first and the other afterwards.

I have played with the `rendered` attribute but it is not working.

Comment: Can you please show your JSF view with the `rendered` attribute(s) in question?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Primefaces you can bind the columns to a collection in the server side, so you can filter and rearrange columns as you like

Example:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml

With plain JSF I don't think that's possible, but you could go with a client approach such reordering the `<td>` elements with jQuery.

Comment: Strictly spoken, Primefaces was not asked in either tags nor in question text. Only JSF2.x was requested.

Comment: And I would discourage using plain HTML/jQuery, some JSF tags with opposite `rendered` attributes (e.g. `empty foo` and `not empty foo`) should do the trick. I can post a full answer when the questioner has posted some content.

Comment: or use a c:foreach with a model backing the order